# Meteor render template if parent has class

Tags: javascript, meteor, handsontable

Hi there I am just wondering. I have a series of collapsible divs from materialize. What I am trying to is if the table header is active render the template. I am using a meteor handsontables package. SO i want the tables to render when active.  SO what i have is.

```
 <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Global What Ifs</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            {{#if isActive}}
                                {{>GlobalWhatIf}}
                            {{/if}}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

AS you can see I only have one template loading at the moment but I do plan on having quiet a few.

Then my js

```
Template.CompanyDetails.onRendered(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});

Template.CompanyDetails.helpers({
    isActive: function(event) {
        return true;
    }
})

Template.CompanyDetails.events({
    'click .collapsible-header' : function(event, template){
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
    }
});
```

I thought maybe I could pass the event target someway in the helper but does not seem to work. Is there someway I can check straight from the handle bars.

Any way some help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried passing the event object via a ```session``` variable?

Comment: Hmm. Like with setting the variable with the event method and then accessing it through the helper? My only issue is will i have to have a different helper for each collapsible div

Comment: You could register a global helper if that's the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
Template.CompanyDetails.onRendered(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});

Template.CompanyDetails.helpers({
    isActive: function() {
       if(Session.get("event")){
        return true;
        Session.set("event",undefined);
    }
  }
})

Template.CompanyDetails.events({
    'click .collapsible-header' : function(event, template){
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
        Session.set("event",event);
    }
});
```

Comment: Are the helps reactive

Comment: @AmyTeresaHyland Yes. Helpers are reactive here because we are making use of Session which is reactive. The only downside I see is that sessions get unset when you refresh the page.